# Simple string replace question in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to replace all occurrences of `\b` with `<b>` and all occurrences  of `\b0` with `</b>` in the following example:

> The quick \b brown fox\b0 jumps over the \b lazy dog\b0.

. Thanks

Comment: what is the question ? are you looking for a regex builder ?

Comment: Steve, I'm stuck with a problem and trying different ways to solve it. No luck so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regular expressions is massive overkill for this (and it often is). A simple:

```
string replace = text.Replace(@"\b0", "</b>")
                     .Replace(@"\b", "<b>");
```

will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need regex for this, you can simply [replace the values with `String.Replace`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)

But if you are curious to know how this could be [done with regex (Regex.Replace)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) here is an example:

```
var pattern = @"\\b0?"; // matches \b or \b0

var result = Regex.Replace(@"The quick \b brown fox\b0 jumps over the \b lazy dog\b0.", pattern,
    (m) =>
    {
        // If it is \b replace with <b>
        // else replace with </b>
        return m.Value == @"\b" ? "<b>" : "</b>";
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\\b0)|(\\b)", 
    m => m.Groups[1].Success ? "</b>" : "<b>");
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick and dirty solution, I would do it in 2 runs: first replace "\b0" with `"</b>"` and then replace "\b" with `"<b>"`.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class FadelMS
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string input = "The quick \b brown fox\b0 jumps over the \b lazy dog\b0.";
      string pattern = "\\b0";
      string replacement = "</b>";
      Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
      string temp = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

      pattern = "\\b";
      replacement = "<b>";
      Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
      string result = rgx.Replace(temp, replacement);

   }
}
```